# Design a class with type defined at class level with wildcard and associate wildcard with specific type while using the class

Tags: java, generics

There is a class :

```
public class RepositoryHolder<T extends Repository<?>> {

      private Map<Class<?>, T> repoMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, T>();

      public <T1> void registerRepo(Class<T1> clazz, T repo){
          repoMap.put(clazz, repo);
      }
}
```

The aim is to link T1 type with the wildcard in Repository <\?>

In the registerRepo() method, clazz type should be associated with T type of repo. For eg: if T=MyRepo1, then only following call should be valid

```
    MyRepo1<String> myrepo1 = new MyRepo1<>();
    registerRepo(String.class, myrepo1 )
```

and not this one :

```
    MyRepo1<Integer> myrepo1 = new MyRepo1<>();
    registerRepo(String.class, myrepo1 )
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: My previous comment was wrong but the preface is the same; my Java is rusty since using Scala, so my answer may not backport I will make it an answer if you confirm it works. Have you tried removing the generic in the Repoholder? then `Map<Class<?>, Repository<?>> repoMap` and `public <T> void registerRepo(Class<T> clazz, Repository<T> repo)`

Comment: If I do this, then I will have a map where the contents could be  `string.class -> RepoType1ForString, integer.class ->   RepoType2ForInteger`. However I would not like to mix RepoType1 and RepoType2 in the same map and rather have RepoType1ForInteger as value for the second key-value pair. Hence the type is defined at Repoholder class level.

Comment: The type defined at class level guards me against mixing RepoType1 with RepoType2. But within a particular repo for eg RepoType1, I am looking for heterogeneity as depicted by `extends Repository<?>`

Comment: Are you sure it does? As far as I'm concerned if I have a generic that is upperbounded by a type, like yours is, then I can pass in anything that is a subtype of that upper bound into the function. But, again, that is relying on my Scala knowledge, and I'm not sure how different Scala and Java actually are in this regard... I can't of course pass a Repo<T> into a a generic field upper bounded by Repo<U> for concrete types U and T even if T extends U. But that's type invariance and that's not exactly what you are after

Comment: Once I do, `return new RepositoryHolder< RepoType1>();`, I am restricting this instance to always have RepoType1

Comment: Ah, of course, my mistake... whoops. Thanks! But yeah, I think what you are after is a higher-kinded type. Basically that means you'd be able to do `T<T1>`, but that I don't think is supported by Java exactly like that. You'd have to do quite a bit to get there... I think I'll wait for someone else to provide a solution before I try and elaborate on that a bit more...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170286/discussion-between-user2599052-and-j-mie6).